# how to make multi-edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to make multiple edittext as this image shown below for login and signup page?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what is `multi edittext` ?

Comment: Just make 2 `EditTexts` with appropriate backgrounds/padding/spacing/etc. Alternatively make them transparent and style their container appropriately.

Comment: @ken wolf any sample codes or link there?

Comment: I've added an answer - it's just the outline but hope you get the idea

Comment: @all five answers are correct.thanks for all answered..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a rounded background first (`/res/drawable/round_rect.xml`):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>

    </shape>
```

Now the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_rect"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="User name"
        android:padding="6dp"
        />
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:padding="6dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/box"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/light_grey" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With `@drawable/box` being an appropriate shape drawable or 9-patch. You would of course have to style the EditTexts and everything appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

//try like this

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_first_name"
            style="@style/style_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/user_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#555533"
            />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/style_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_login_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <requestFocus>
                </requestFocus>
            </EditText>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/LightGrey" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners        
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />        


    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.3dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

color

```
<color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just one on top of another, and then you play with the background. There is no such thing as double `EditText`